# Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

Why is the recurrence relation of recursive factorial algorithm this?

```
T(n)=1 for n=0
T(n)=1+T(n-1) for n>0
```

Why is it not this?

```
T(n)=1 for n=0
T(n)=n*T(n-1) for n>0
```

Putting values of n i.e 1,2,3,4...... the second recurrence relation holds(The factorials are correctly calculated) not the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is very confusing... You first formula is not factorial. It is simply T(n) = n + 1, for all n. Factorial of n is the product of the first n positive integers: factorial(1) = 1. factorial(n) = n * factorial(n-1). Your second formula is essentially correct.

Comment: So what is the time complexity for the second algorithm??

Is it exponential?

Comment: I think I saw the first recurrence relation here

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=HuQoLslcbwEC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=factorial+recursive+algorithm+time+complexity&source=bl&ots=aDC9EmOFge&sig=hztXrziSgZ1VAfMsptm_3MaP0iA&hl=en&ei=_CmhSo2sKt6OjAfxmozADg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8#v=onepage&q=factorial%20recursive%20algorithm%20time%20complexity&f=false

Comment: The theoretical time complexity is linear.  To compute a factorial of n you need to perform n multiplications: O(n).  The value of n!, on the other hand grows faster than any exponential.  Of course, the complexity of computing n! increases if you want full precision for a large n, so that n! has more bits than the integer on your machine.  Then you need to perform infinite precision arithmetic, which adds complexity.

Comment: even with your pointer, i'm not able to find the right relation. Are you sure you were not looking at the Fibonacci number ? (it's closer but not right either..)

Comment: This is called "flat recursion", i. e. the function only makes one recursive call to itself.  Flat recursion takes liner time to compute.  On the other hand, if the function makes more than one call to itself, you have a deep recursion, that takes exponential time.  Example: f(x) = f(x-1) + f(x-2).  At each level of recursion you double the number of calls to f, i. e. f() is called 2^n times.

Comment: >>The theoretical time complexity is linear.

Can it be proven using the recurrence relation??

Comment: Another point: please be careful not to confuse the bound on the time it takes to compute a function, and the bound on the value it returns.  The bound on the time it takes to compute n! is O(n).  The bound on the value of n! is O(n!) > O(k^n) for any k.

Comment: @Prasoon Sure.  To compute n! recursively you make n recursive calls.

Comment: @Dima<br>

If you try solving its recurrence relation will u get T(n)=O(n) ?

The recurrence relation is 

T(n)=1 when n=0
T(n)=n*T(n-1) when n=0

How T(n)=O(n).??

Comment: Ok, I see. What you are after is the bound on the value of T(n). In that case no, T(n) != O(n). T(n) = O(n!) > O(k^n) for any

Answer (score 12):

we generally use recurrence relation **to find the time complexity of algorithm.**

---

Here, the function T(n) is not actually for calculating the value of an factorial but it is telling you about the time complexity of the factorial algorithm.

---

It means for finding a factorial of n it will take 1 more operation than factorial of n-1
(i.e. T(n)=T(n-1)+1) and so on.

---

so correct recurrence relation for a recursive factorial algorithm is
T(n)=1 for n=0
T(n)=1+T(n-1) for n>0
not that you mentioned later.

---

like recurrence for tower of hanoi is
T(n)=2T(n-1)+1 for n>0;

Update:
It does not have anything to do with implementation generally.
But recurrence can give an intuition of programming paradigm for eg if T(n)=2*T(n/2)+n (merge sort) this gives kind of intuition for divide and conquer because we are diving n into half.

Also, If you will solve the equation it will give you a bound on running time.eg big oh notation.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like T(n) is the recurrence relation of the *time complexity* of the recursive factorial algorithm, assuming constant time multiplication. Perhaps you misread your source?

Answer (score 6):

What he put was not the factorial recursion, but the time complexity of it.
Assuming this is the pseudocode for such a recurrence:

```
1. func factorial(n)
2.   if (n == 0)
3.      return 1
4.   return n * (factorial - 1)
```

- I am assuming that tail-recursion elimination is not involved.

Line 2 and 3 costs a constant time, c1 and c2.
Line 4 costs a constant time as well. However, it calls factorial(n-1) which will take some time T(n-1). Also, the time it takes to multiply factorial(n-1) by n can be ignored once T(n-1) is used.
Time for the whole function is just the sum: T(n) = c1 + c2 + T(n-1).
This, in big-o notation, is reduced to T(n) = 1 + T(n-1).

This is, as Diam has pointed out, is a flat recursion, therefore its running time should be O(n). Its space complexity will be enormous though.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you have bad information.  The second recurrence relation you cite *is* the correct one, as you have observed.  The first one just generates the natural numbers.

Answer (score 3):

T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 is correct recurrence equation for factorial of n.
This equation gives you the time to compute factorial of n NOT value of the factorial of n.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you find the first one ? It's completely wrong.

It's only going to add 1 each time whatever the value is .

Answer (score 2):

First you have to find a basic operation and for this example it is multiplication. Multiplication happens once in every recursion. So 
T(n) = T(n-1) +1 
this +1 is basic operation (mutliplication for this example)
T(n-1) is next recursion call.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: The answer to your question actually depends on **what sequence** your recurrence relation is *defining*. That is, whether the sequence *T<sub>n</sub>* in your question represents *the factorial function* or *the running-time cost of computing the factorial function*<sup>X</sup>.

---

#### The factorial function

The *recursive* defintion of the factorial of *n*, *f<sub>n</sub>*, is:

*f<sub>n</sub> = n • f<sub>n-1</sub>* for *n > 0* with  *f<sub>0</sub> = 1*.

As you can see, the equation above is actually a *recurrence relation*, since it is an *equation* that, together with the *initial term* (i.e., *f<sub>0</sub> = 1*), *recursively* defines a *sequence* (i.e., the factorial function, *f<sub>n</sub>*).

---

#### Modelling the running-time cost of computing the factorial

Now, we are going to find a *model* for representing the running-time cost of computing the factorial of *n*. Let's call *T<sub>n</sub>* the *running-time cost* of computing *f<sub>n</sub>*.

Looking at the definition above of the factorial function *f<sub>n</sub>*, its running-time cost *T<sub>n</sub>* will consist of the running-time cost of computing *f<sub>n-1</sub>* (i.e., this cost is *T<sub>n-1</sub>*) plus the running-time cost of performing the multiplication between *n* and *f<sub>n-1</sub>*.  The multiplication is achieved in constant time. Therefore we could say that *T<sub>n</sub> = T<sub>n-1</sub> + 1*.

However, what is the value of *T<sub>0</sub>*? *T<sub>0</sub>* represents the running-time cost of computing *f<sub>0</sub>*. Since the value of *f<sub>0</sub>* is initially known by definition, the running-time cost for computing *f<sub>0</sub>* is actually constant. Therefore, we could say that *T<sub>0</sub> = 1*.

Finally, what we obtain is:

*T<sub>n</sub> = T<sub>n-1</sub> + 1* for *n > 0* with *T<sub>0</sub> = 1*.

This equation above is also a *recurrence relation*. However, what it defines (together with the initial term), is a sequence that *models the running-time cost of computing the factorial function*.

---

<sup>X</sup><sub>Taking into account how the sequence in your recurrence relation is called (i.e., *T<sub>n</sub>*), I think it very likely represents the latter, i.e., *the running-time cost of computing the factorial function*.</sub>