# Recurrence relation on Factorial

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, factorial, recurrence

I was studying recurrence by a slide found at (slide 7 and 8):

http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cop3502h/spring2012/Lectures/Lec8_RecurrenceRelations.pdf

I just can't accept (probably I`m not seeing it right) that the recurrence equation of factorial is :

> T(n) = T(n-1)+2
>   T(1) = 1

when considering the number of operations ("*" and "-") of the function :

```
int factorial(int n) {
 if (n == 1)
 return 1;
 return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

If we use n = 5 we will get 6  by the formula above while the real number of subs and molts are 8.

My teacher also told us that if analyzing only the number of "*" it would be :

> T(n) = T(n-1)+1.

Again if I use n = 5, I would get 5 but if you do it on a paper you will get 4 multiplications.

I also checked on the forum, but this Question is more messed then a hell :
[Recurrence Relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379929/recurrence-relation)

Anyone could help me understand that ? thanks.

Comment: You don't get T(5) = 6 as you claim.  Calculate T(2), then T(3), then ..., then T(5) to see what you do get.

Comment: I see it now, I wasn`t doing the math right here. Thanks.

Comment: The factorial algorithm is fine, don't get where you got the "T(1) = 1; T(n) = T(n-1) + 2" because it's not the factorial equation that's for sure...

Comment: I gave it another look and it's not clear in the slides but like @irrelephant says looks like they are counting both the multiplication and the subtraction, the return is counted as an operation when n equals 1. Though it could be clearer in the materials. Let me note that from what I learned in math the equation in the slides is missing the statement for 0!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if we use n = 5 we will get 6 by the formula above while the real number of subs and molts are 8.

It seems that the slides are counting the number of operations, not just subtractions and multiplications. In particular, the return statement is counted as one operation. (The slides say, "if it’s the base case just one operation to return.")

Thus, the real number of subtractions and multiplications is 8, but the number of operations is 9. If n is 5, then, unrolling the recursion, we get 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 = 9 operations, which looks right to me.

Comment: you are right, but even if it`s 9 then why I will get only 6 by the reccurrence formula ?

Comment: By the recurrence, you should get 9. T(1) = 1, T(2) = 3, T(3) = 5, T(4) = 7, T(5) = 9.

Comment: how do you got t(3) = 5 ? (I`m not saying you are wrong, just trying to understand how this reccurrence thing works)

Comment: T(3) = T(2) + 2 = T(1) + 2 + 2 = 1 + 2 + 2 = 5.

Comment: You are damm right! Thanks a lot for the explanation.